# Error when creating a customer using test card

Tags: node.js, express, stripe-payments, stripe.js

When attempting to begin a Subscription for a newly created Customer, I receive the following error from Stripe:

> `invalid_request_error`
>   Error: This customer has no attached payment source

The customer seems to be created just fine. I am using Stripe Checkout to collect the card token. For testing, I am using Stripe's `4242 4242 4242 4242` card number with random information. The token seems to be getting created and passed to my server just fine. Below is my server side code:

```
stripe.plans.retrieve(
    "basic-monthly",
    function(err, plan) {
        if (err) {
            console.error(err)
            res.sendStatus(500)
        } else {
            stripe.customers.create({
                email: owner,
                source: token.id,
            }, function(err, customer) {
                if (err) {
                    console.error(err)
                    res.sendStatus(500)
                  } else {
                    stripe.subscriptions.create({
                      customer: customer.id,
                      items: [
                        {
                          plan: "basic-monthly",
                          quantity: 1
                        },
                      ],
                    }, function(err, subscription) {
                      if (err) {
                        console.error(err)
                        console.log('@@@@@ UNABLE TO CREATE SUBSCRIPTION @@@@')
                        res.sendStatus(500)
                      } else {
                         console.log('Subscription created.')
                         console.dir(subscription)
                         res.sendStatus(200);
                      }     
                    });
                  }
                });
              }
            });
```

`@@@@@ UNABLE TO CREATE SUBSCRIPTION @@@@` is logged, along with the errors described above. I understand what the error means, but I am not sure how it is occurring. As you can see above, I am passing in the Token Id when creating a customer, `source: token.id,`.

What is the issue here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The most likely cause here is that `token.id` is empty, so the Customer is being created without a Source.  I'd suggest logging the contents of `token` and see what you get.

Comment: `token.id` is not empty, and contains the token id passed from the client Checkout flow.

Comment: I was mistaken, I thought `token.id` was just fine as when I print it at the beginning of my route, it prints to the console as expected. I just added a log statement directly above the call to `stripe.customers.create()` and it is in fact somehow `undefined`. How is this possible? It's the exact same variable, and not being modified anywhere in my route.

Comment: So turns out the token was being turned into a String via `JSON.stringify()` on the client. It printed to the console with all it's contents, but naturally `token.id` returned undefined. I appreciate the help.